# Excel How to find duplicate cells or values in a row?

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have a dataset in which each row belongs to a unique person so what I want to do is that find duplicate values in each row.

I tried using conditional formatting but its very time consuming as I have to apply it to each individual row otherwise it will find duplicates among all rows not just one row.

[image]

Could you please suggest something that can help me it can be formula or vba or formula for conditional formatting.

I used macro recorder to create a macro and the results is below. If I can make it go through a range of rows and apply the formatting that could help

```
Sub DuplicatesRow1() ' ' DuplicatesRow Macro '

'
    Rows("251:251").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Rows("252:252").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Rows("253:253").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("E259").Select End Sub
```

Comment: this seems like a bad design flaw in Excel. You did put the `excel-vba` tag in here. Have you made any attempts with code to accomplish this? If so, please provide what you have tried. Otherwise, the question risks getting down-voted and closed. The other option - and perhaps less time-consuming the enter a format for each row - is to copy and paste formats from row-to-row; though this obviously is cumbersome for numerous row amounts.

Comment: Also, if you provide an example with some sample data to elaborate on your problem, this increases your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Vba code added

Comment: @Michael Example added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a loop that will set a conditional format on each row. I used sheet and range references based on your sample data and code. You modify these to fit your exact data set.

I will also note that I am concerned about this causing performance issues in Excel if there are numerous rows, as the amount of Formats may seriously raise your file size and affect performance.

```
Sub LoopCF()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

'Dim lRow As Long
'lRow = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row 'will give row 200 as long as contiguous rows

Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("B2:B200") 'ws.Range("B2:B" & lRow)

For Each cel In rng

    With cel.Resize(1, 4)

        .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

        With .FormatConditions(1)

            .DupeUnique = xlDuplicate

            With .Font
                .Color = -16383844
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 13551615
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

            .StopIfTrue = False

        End With

    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting error when running this code. I will tinker with it when I get home. Also could you clarify what lRow = ws.Range("A251").End(xlDown).Row and Set rng = ws.Range("B251:B" & lRow) are used for, the two values are confusing me? Say I want to apply this to row 2 till 200 how would I do that?

Comment: @AAZ - see my edited code. `lRow` just gets the last row in the Range and `rng` sets the desired range to work with to an object, so it can work on that object. Also, if you tell me the error you get and on which line, I can probably assist :)

Comment: I tried the updated code and this time no errors but it does not do anything :( The name of the sheet is Sheet1.

Comment: Could other method be to have a loop that applies the formatting to a row then adds one to Rows("251:251").Select thus making it Rows("252:252").Select and so on. It could ask something like how many rows do you want to apply it to enter a number and then it starts from 2 until that row number defined by the user

Comment: @AAZ - try now. I took out some stuff I thought may be unnecessary, but perhaps it is. This code is going `row-by-row` via looping through each cell in the row. You could use an input-box and counter, though, if you like.

Comment: Tried the updated code and now I am getting error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: try now `.StopIfTrue = False` needs to be in the `With .FormatConditions(1)` block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101414/discussion-between-a-az-and-scott-holtzman).

Answer (score 1):

I further worked on this and managed to come up with the following code which seems to be working for me. I am new to VBA and do not have enough experience so please let me know if my code can be improved further

```
Private Sub HighlightDuplicateRow(row As Integer)

Dim report As Worksheet
Set report = Excel.ActiveSheet
report.Cells(row, row).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub


Sub DuplicatesInEachRow()
Dim counter As Integer, limit As Variant
counter = 2
limit = InputBox("Give me last row number", "Highlight Duplicates in a Row")
If limit = "" Then Exit Sub
Do Until counter > limit
Call HighlightDuplicateRow(counter)
counter = counter + 1
Loop
End Sub
```